# Does Scala's 2.9.1 compiler throw away type parameter information?

Tags: java, generics, scala, interop

I'm writing some Java code that depends on some Scala code (that I have also written).  Trying to supply an argument with a parameterized type seems to work if the Scala is compiled with 2.8.0 but fail if I use 2.9.1.

The (simplified) Scala code looks roughly like this:

```
package test

import collection.JavaConversions._

class SomeClass {
  def foo(numbers: java.util.Set[Long]) {
    numbers.foreach(println(_))
  }
}
```

This compiles happily with both the 2.8.0 and 2.9.1 compilers.  The Java code looks something like this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass().foo(new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L)));
    }

}
```

If I compile the Scala with the 2.8.0 compiler, then the Java will compile happily (with Java's 1.6.0_26 compiler).  However, if I compile the Scala with 2.9.1, then the Java compiler fails with the error:

```
test\App.java:16: foo(java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>) in test.SomeClass cannot be applied to (java.util.HashSet<java.lang.Long>)
            sc.foo(new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L)));
              ^
1 error
```

So it seems that while Scala 2.8.0 retains in the bytecode the information that `numbers` is of type `Set<Long>`, the 2.9.1 compiler emits bytecode where `numbers` is a `Set<Object>`.

Is this a bug?  Is it an unfortunate (for me) side-effect of a deliberate change? (The Scala [changelog](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43) mentions "various fixes in ... `JavaConversions` for smoother interoperation").  If so, is there anything I can do to get this to work with 2.9.1?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried being explicit with java.util.Set[java.lang.Long] ? scala Long is not java Long (more like java long). It does not allow null. So maybe it stopped pretending between 2.8 and 2.9

Comment: Woo! Thanks - that works :) Does anyone know if that was an intentional/documented change? It does seem a bit curious... Also, if you put your comment as an answer then I can up-vote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as my shot in the dark in comment proved lucky, same as an answer.

It works with

```
def foo(numbers: java.util.Set[java.lang.Long])
```

`java.lang.Long` is not the same as the `Long` of scala. Notably, `Set[java.lang.Long]` can contain `null`, a `Set[Long]` should not (unless the type system was circumvented with some sort of unchecked cast). This is in spite of the `Set` being implemented as containing references in both case; in the second case, they are guaranteed to be non null.

Identifying `Set[Long]` and `Set[java.lang.Long]` opens a loophole in the type system. That being said, I don't know whether the change was intended.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, it's complicated. `Any` in the Scala type system is a great unifier, but a complete fiction by the time you're in Java-land.

The simplified view taken prior to 2.9 was ill-conceived and broke things.

To get a feel for the rock-and-a-hard-place nature of the problem, read Paul Phillips' accounts from the mailing lists:

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9157

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8888

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8980

Comment: Oooh... thorny :s Thanks for the links - I don't know enough bytecode to follow the details, but Mr Phillips seems to know what he's talking about so I shall take it this change was necessary!